# How to integrate Facebook & Google login with AWS Cognito for iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I am integrating AWS Cognito with iOS app(written in Objective C). I want to implement Facebook login and Google+ login with it so that user can login via any of these social providers and get authenticated by AWS Cognito (User Pool/Identity Pool)and get access to other AWS services.

I have read the documentations available at [Facebook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html) and [Google](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html) to user Identity pool to authenticate, but could not succeed. I am getting error as Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool'. Can anyone help here? If anyone shares a code that works well (no AWS sample apps, CognitoSync, CogntiAuth - I tried them as well, but did not help), will be highly appreciated.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: By creating Federated Identities and adding google+ and user pool app client_id etc info to the Federated Identities I got rid of that error. But don't know what to do after that.

Comment: any update guys?